# Nokogiri 1.6.8 is installed but gives error for previous Nokogiri when running "bundle install"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, redmine

We had a server shutdown and Redmine stopped working, so I had to reinstall Bundler and run `bundle install`.

While running `bundle install` I get this error:

```
c:\APPS\webapps\redmine-3.2.0>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 12.3.2
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Using i18n 0.9.5
Using json 1.8.6
Using minitest 5.11.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using activesupport 4.2.5
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
Fetching nokogiri 1.9.1 (x64-mingw32)
Installing nokogiri 1.9.1 (x64-mingw32)
Gem::RuntimeRequirementNotMetError: nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.2, <
2.6. The current ruby version is 2.0.0.
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.9.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.9.1' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails was resolved to 4.2.5, which depends on
    actionmailer was resolved to 4.2.5, which depends on
      actionpack was resolved to 4.2.5, which depends on
        actionview was resolved to 4.2.5, which depends on
          rails-dom-testing was resolved to 1.0.9, which depends on
            nokogiri
```

I already installed Nokogiri 1.6.8. I'm not sure why it cannot read the Nokogiri version that I installed and still fetches 1.9.1 because I need Ruby v. 2 for Redmine 2.3.0, however my bundle is still telling me that it is looking for 1.9.1. While doing `bundle install` I tried changing the Gemfile based on my research to `gem "nokogiri", ">= 1.4.2"` however 1.9.1 is persisting. How can I successfully upgrade Nokogiri?

I used:

```
gem "nokogiri", "1.6.8"
```

In my Gemfile I have:

```
c:\APPS\webapps\redmine-3.2.0>bundle update nokogiri
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies....
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "nokogiri":
  In Gemfile:
    nokogiri (= 1.6.8) java

    roadie-rails java was resolved to 1.2.0, which depends on
      roadie (~> 3.1) java was resolved to 3.5.0, which depends on
        nokogiri (~> 1.8) java
```

If I run what `gem install nokogiri -v '1.9.1'`, I get an error that my Ruby version is lower than expected and I cannot have a higher Ruby version because Redmine is an old version.

Here are all the Nokogiri versions I have:

```
c:\APPS\webapps\redmine-3.2.0>gem uninstall nokogiri
YAML safe loading is not available. Please upgrade psych to a version that supports safe loading (>= 2.0).

    Select gem to uninstall:
    1. nokogiri-1.6.8.rc3-x64-mingw32
    2. nokogiri-1.6.8-x64-mingw32
    3. nokogiri-1.6.8.1-x64-mingw32
    4. All versions
```

Comment: If you specify `nokogiri >= 1.4.2`, you'll get the latest. Which in this case is 1.9.1, which requires Ruby 2.2. Try specifying the exact version of nokogiri you want. Maybe something like `~> 1.6`.

Comment: should I say nokogiri = 1.6.8?

Comment: `gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.8'`

Comment: it says Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "nokogiri":

Comment: Looks like road requires 1.8+, so you'll want to specify something like `~> 1.8`. Looking thru nokogiri docs, 1.9.1 looks like where 2.0 support was dropped so you need to find something less than that, but greater than 1.8. It's not clear why bundler isn't resolving this for you, but there may be something in your Gemfile.lock that's causing it (or maybe someone ran a bundle update without any arguments)

Comment: *"maybe someone ran a bundle update without any arguments"* -- This. It looks like your dependencies have been messed up due to someone running `bundle update`. If your code is in source control, you could try reverting whatever the breaking update was; otherwise you'll need to go through and reverse-engineer downgrading libraries as needed to get your setup working again.

Comment: ...Or, you could try to upgrade *everything* -- i.e. use a modern ruby version and a modern redmine version. Your setup is stuck in limbo since several dependencies are updated whilst others are not; and the result is incompatible - hence the errors.

Comment: Redmine 3.2 supports Ruby up to version 2.2. You will make life much simpler if you first update Ruby to 2.2 and then subsequently upgrade Redmine to a newer version (at least 3.4). There, you can then again update Ruby to a newer (supported) version such as Ruby 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not fix this issue. It was looping through upgrades and downgrades, so after much frustration I tried Ruby 2.6 that Redmine 4.2 claimed to be compatible, which still had issues. I downgraded to Ruby 2.3 and it worked, then I migrated my database according to the redmine.org documentation and almost everything is functional, and I got a feedback that it is much faster.

According to my experience, you will have your Redmine database still working so don't worry that it s the same version.